# Dailogflow not extracting the parameters from a input

Tags: dialogflow-es

In DialogFlow, I have created a intent where I have provided a few Training Phrases as shown in the figure. 
But whenever I ask a new phrases its just not able to detect or extract the new parameters from that text.

I have saved the intent and it trains for a few seconds but still not change. Please describe me why this is happening and how to make it work. Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given-name its basically an entity already created in Dialogflow with many names, probably even in English. Are you sure your input is an english name? 
As a solution there is a wild card @sys.any otherwiser you have to create a new entity with maaaaany names.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So i tried, it works for common english names like Sam, Dan etc. but not for the ones I want it to work like yoda, chewbacca. How can i make it detect these as well as a parameter?

Comment: I really think that you have to create another entity and insert all the names you need. There is nothing much you can do..